# Where to put gedit macros plugin?

Tags: gedit, plugins

Please, in which folder should I put the gedit plug-in files for macros?

OK, this may be marked duplicate, but I have tried, last time creating a folder as indicated by gedit help:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2QH0.jpg

The following does not seem to be the right folder. I have tried putting the three files .la .so .gedit-plugin there.

~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/
~/.gnome2/gedit/plugins/

Thank you for all good help I have received here in the past.

I use v. 16.04

Comment: .local/share/gedit/plugins is the correct place, maybe the plugin isn't compatible with gedit version in 16.04. Post a link to plugin if you want.

Comment: In this [page](https://code.google.com/archive/p/gedit-macro-plugin/downloads) I chose the [file](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/gedit-macro-plugin/gedit-macro-plugin-1.2_x86_64.tar.gz) on top. I expanded the archive and put the three files obtained from archive folder "build" into the directory you mention.

Comment: This might be tricky? For me it is not the end of the world if it doesn't work. In the 80's I used vi so now I am slowly adapting to that again. Might be the best solution in the long run for me. (But if it is not possible to make macros work with the current gedit, maybe there should be information about that somewhere, so people just don't try, try and ask?)

Comment: Well that plugin is from 2010, it's now 2016. Maybe look for a more recent plugin

Comment: I will do that. I am also getting into vim again, now.  That (and also emacs, I guess) is probably the best option for me, I just lose speed between the occasions I use it. / Strange that macros are often not given high priority in editors, I think they really help. / Always a big thank you, to you and the other members that help out. It is always good to know that someone else is checking out a problem. Most often a solution comes up and I get my actions double checked.